# Can you write Javascript object init shorthand C# style?

Tags: c#, javascript

I have the following Javascript:

```
function TestModel()
{
        this.name = "Testvalue";
        this.id = 0;
}

var test = new TestModel();
alert(test.name);
```

If I want to initialize an object with different parameters without the use of a constructor I would need to call the following code:

```
var test = new TestModel();
test.name = "other value";
test.id = 5;
alert(test.name);
```

What I would like to do is something similar to the C# style:

```
class TestModel
{
    public string name = "Testvalue";
    public int id = 0;
}

TestModel test = new TestModel() { name = "other value", id = 5 };
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(test.name);
```

But if I try something like that in javascript it won't work.

In short: I am trying to init a object in 1 line without the use of a constructor. Is this possible in javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by "without the use of a constructor"? You are already using a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks most like the C# syntax:

```
function TestModel(init)
{
   init = init || {}; 
   this.name = init.name || "Testvalue";
   this.id = init.id || 0;
}

var test1 = new TestModel( { name:'testvalue1',id:1 } );
var test2 = new TestModel( { name:'testvalue2',id:2 } );
```

Comment: This looks closest to what I want. I need to write around a few things (while converting my C# to javascript). Thx.

Answer (score 3):

```
function TestModel(name, id)
{
  this.name = name || "TestValue";
  this.id = id || 0;
}

var test = new TestModel("Your Name", 4638);
alert(test.name);
```

Comment: (+1)

you could also say `this.name = name||"TestValue;"` to save Lines

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one for you that's like the one KooiInc gave but a little more generic and also checks to make sure that the values passed are of the right type....

```
function TestModel(init) {
    var defaults = {
        name: "Bunyip",
        id: 0
    }
    if (typeof init == 'object') {
        for (var prop in defaults) {
            if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                if (init.hasOwnProperty(prop) && typeof init[prop] == typeof defaults[prop]) {
                    this[prop] = init[prop];
                } else {
                    this[prop] = defaults[prop];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var prop in defaults) {
            if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(prop)) this[prop] = defaults[prop];
        }
    }
    delete defaults;
}

var test1 = new TestModel( { name:'testvalue1',id:1 } );
var test2 = new TestModel( { name:'testvalue2',id:2 } );
```